# Node.js - Check if stream has error before piping response

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

In Node.js, say that I want to read a file from somewhere and stream the response (e.g., from the filesystem using `fs.createReadStream()`).

```
application.get('/files/:id', function (request, response) {
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/saved-files/' + request.params.id);
    var mimeType = getMimeTypeSomehow(request.params.id);
    if (mimeType === 'application/pdf') {
        response.set('Content-Range', ...);
        response.status(206);
    } else {
        response.status(200);
    }
    readStream.pipe(response);
});
```

However, I want to detect if there is an error with the stream before sending my response headers. How do I do that?

Pseudocode:

```
application.get('/files/:id', function (request, response) {
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/saved-files/' + request.params.id);
    readStream.on('ready', function () {
        var mimeType = getMimeTypeSomehow(request.params.id);
        if (mimeType === 'application/pdf') {
            response.set('Content-Range', ...);
            response.status(206);
        } else {
            response.status(200);
        }
        readStream.pipe(response);
    });
    readStream.on('error', function () {
        response.status(404).end();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write stream is ended when readStream ends or has an error. You can prevent this default behaviour by passing `end:false` during pipe and end the write stream manually.

So even if the error occurs, your write stream is still open and you can do other stuff(e.g. sending 404 status) with writestream in the `error` callback.

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/saved-files/' + request.params.id);
readStream.on('error', function () {
    res.status(404).end();
});
readStream.on('end', function(){
  res.end(); //end write stream manually when readstream ends
})
readStream.pipe(res,{end:false}); // prevent default behaviour
```

---

**Update 1**: For file streams, you can listen for `open` event to check if the file is ready to read:

```
readStream.on('open', function () {
    // set response headers and status
});
```

---

**Update 2**: As OP mentioned there may be no `open` event for other streams, we may use the following if the stream is inherited from node's stream module. The trick is we write the data manually instead of `pipe()` method. That way we can do some 'initialization' on writable before starting to write first byte.

So we bind `once('data')` first and then bind `on('data')`. First one will be called before actual writing is happened.

```
readStream
.on('error',function(err) {
  res.status(404).end();
})
.once('data',function(){ 
  //will be called once and before the on('data') callback
  //so it's safe to set headers here
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
})
.on('data', function(chunk){ 
  //now start writing data 
  res.write(chunk);
})
.on('end',res.end.bind(res)); //ending writable when readable ends
```

Comment: It's important that I be able to set headers in the case of no errors. I updated my question to make this more obvious. In some cases the status may even be `206`.

Comment: for file streams there is `open` event that can be used to check if file exists and is opened. I'll update my answer

Comment: This is useful for file streams. Unfortunately it won't work for other streams in my stack; e.g., I might want to stream files from Amazon AWS, but they don't emit an `open` event from streams obtained via `s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()`.

Comment: @Jackson, added alternative solution, but don't know if it'll work for your stream.

Comment: Thanks, it did work for both `fs` streams and `s3` streams!

Comment: Have in mind that if the file is to big, you're not handling the backpressure correctly, and you will exhaust the memory of the script.